# Generar un archivo SQL con Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Quiero realizar un backup de ciertas tablas de mi base de datos un `.SQL` desde php utilizando el framework `Codeigniter` 
¿Alguna idea de como realizar esto? Estoy en 0

Answer (score 2):

`CodeIgniter` cuenta con una clase de gestión de base de datos, para ello haremos uso de la clase `dbutil` y los helper `file` (opcional) y `download` para guardar el fichero y descargarlo respectivamente:

```
//Hacemos el backup de los datos que nos interesan
$prefs = array(
        'tables'        => array('tabla1', 'tabla2'),   // Listado de tablas.
        'ignore'        => array(),                     // Listado de tablas a omitir
        'format'        => 'zip',                       // gzip, zip, txt
        'filename'      => 'backup.zip',                // Nombre del fichero - SOLAMENTE PARA FICHEROS ZIP
        'add_drop'      => TRUE,                        // Si agregar la sentencia DROP TABLE al backup
        'add_insert'    => TRUE,                        // Si agregar la sentencia INSERT al backup
        'newline'       => "\n"                         // Salto de línea
);
$backup = $this->dbutil->backup($prefs);

//Cargamos el helper file y generamos un fichero
//Esta parte la usamos solo si deseamos guardarlo en servidor
$this->load->helper('file');
write_file('bk/backup.zip', $backup);

//Cargamos el helper download y forzamos la descarga
$this->load->helper('download');
force_download('backup.zip', $backup);
```

En las opciones del backup `$prefs` si deseamos hacer backup de la db entera, simplemente pasamos un `array` vacío en vez de `tabla1`, `tabla2`.

Un saludo,